# How can I specify a subset of a 1-D array as the send or receive buffer in MPI.NET for C#?

Tags: c#, mpi

I am learning C# parallel programming using MPI.NET. In the example given below, I define a 1-D array (x) in each process and then I do some simple calculation on the corresponding part assigned to that process (i.e only the assigned part of x) to obtain its corresponding part in (y). My primary interest is to gather all these assigned parts (part of y calculated on each process) into the y-array on the root process to be able to finally calculate the sum. I mean, I want to copy each assigned part from all processes on the corresponding part on y-array located on root process.However, I could not do it; the only thing I could do was to gather 1-D arrays into a 2-D array or to gather all of them on a new defined 1-D array with the size of "comm.size*y.length". As I searched, using "MPI_Gather ($sendbuf , sendcnt, sendtype, &recbuf, recvcount, root, comm)" keyword in C++ we are able to do this task, HOWEVER, as it seams to me that "MPI.Gather" in C# is different and it does not have the flexibility of MPI_Gather in C++. I need to gather all the calculated parts of y in each process into the corresponding location in the y-array on root process. In other words, how can I specify a subset of an array as the send or receive buffer in MPI.NET for C#. I would appreciate it if you help me in this matter.

```
            using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))
        {

            double sumSerial = 0;
            double sumParallel = 0;
            int arraySize = 100000;
            double[] x = new double[arraySize];
            double[] y = new double[arraySize];

            Intracommunicator comm = Communicator.world;

            int numProc = comm.Size;

            int numItr = arraySize / numProc;


            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                x[i] = i;
                sumSerial += i;
            }


            int firstInx = comm.Rank * numItr;
            int lastInx = firstInx + numItr;


            for (int i = firstInx; i < lastInx; i++)
            {

                y[i] = 5.0 * x[i];


            }


            //double[][] zz=comm.Gather<double[]>(y,0);
            double[] z = comm.GatherFlattened(y, 0);

            comm.Barrier();


            if (comm.Rank==0)
            {

                //for (int i = 0; i < numProc; i++)
                //{
                //    for (int j = 0; j < zz[0].Length; j++)
                //    {
                //        sumParallel += zz[i][j];
                //    }

                //}

                for (int i = 0; i < z.Length; i++)
                {
                    sumParallel += z[i];
                }



                Console.WriteLine("sum_Parallel: {0}; sum_Serial= {1}; 
                    Ratio: {2}; z_length: {3}", sumParallel, sumSerial,
                    sumParallel / sumSerial, z.Length);


            }



        }
```